# moving pieces and printing them in Snake&Ladders

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I would like to know how can i move my pieces and printing back the board with the pieces in my multidimensional array.My board game is not done. I cannot continue until i figure out how to move the pieces in the array with the dice.
This is the code i have so far for my snake and ladder board game.

```
//Function to determine if the player wants to play the game or not
function enter(){
    var play=prompt("Want to start the game?\n O/N");
    if(play=="o"||play=="O"){
        table(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8);    
        var start=prompt("Against System/Player:");
        if (start=="Player"||start=="player"){

            commencer();
        }
            else if(start=="System"||start=="system"){

                system();
            }
        }
    else if(play=="N"||play=="n"||play==null){
        print("If you want to play type enter()");
    }
    }

//Function to start the game
function commencer(){
    alert("The dice will be rolled to determine who will start p1 or p2");
    var roll1=reroll();
    var roll2=reroll();
    var p1=roll1;
    var p2=roll2;
    alert("P1 rolled: " +roll1+ "\nP2 rolled: " +roll2);

    if(p1>p2){
        alert("P1 will start...");
        player1();
        }
        else if(p2>p1){
        alert("P2 will start...");
        }
        else
            reroll();

}

//Function to start the game with p1
function system(){//function Not done

    var p1=prompt("Would you like to roll the dice?\n O/N");

    var p1position=1;
    var systemposition=1;

    var diceroll1=0;

    var p1roll=1;
    var systemroll=1;

    var snakeladder=new Array(8);
    snakeladder[0]=col3[5][3];
    snakeladder[1]=col8[4][1];
    snakeladder[2]=col4[3][2];
    snakeladder[3]=col1[2][0];
    snakeladder[4]=col3[0][2];
    snakeladder[5]=col3[4][1];
    snakeladder[6]=col6[3][2];
    snakeladder[7]=col7[0][2];

    while(p1=="o"||p1=="O"){
        p1roll=de();
        systemroll=de();

        print("P1 a lance:" +p1roll+ "\nSystem a lance:" +systemroll);

        p1position+=p1roll;
        systemposition+=systemroll;

        p1position=getp(p1position,p1roll,snakeladder);
        //not done..
    }
}

//Function to reroll the dice
function reroll(){
    var relancer1=de();
    var relancer2=de();

    return relancer1 && relancer2;

        }

//Function for rolling the dice    
function de(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}




//Function to print the board without the players
function table(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8){

for(var i=0; i<col1.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<col1[i].length;j++){
        print(col1[i][j]+col2[i][j]+col3[i][j]+col4[i][j]+col5[i][j]+col6[i][j]+col7[i][j]+col8[i][j]);
    }
}
}

var col1=[[" ___","|   |","|   |","|___|"],
         ["|   |","|   |","|___|","|   |"],
         ["| E |","|___|","|   |","|   |"],
         ["|___|","|   |","|   |","|___|"],
         ["|   |","|   |","|___|","|   |"],
         ["| P |","|___|","|   |","|   |"],
         ["|___|"]];

var col2=[[" ___","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col3=[[" ___","   |", " S |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |"," S |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |"," E |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col4=[[" ___","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |"," P |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |"," E |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col5=[[" ___","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col6=[[" ___","   |"," P |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         [" P |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |"," S |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col7=[[" ___","   |"," S |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];

var col8=[[" ___","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |","   |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|","   |","   |","___|"],
         ["   |"," E |","___|","   |"],
         ["   |","___|","   |","   |"],
         ["___|"]];
enter();
```

This is how the board will look like without the numbers. Was using this side board as a reference for the positions.

```
 c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8
 ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
|64 |63 |62 |61 |60 |59 |58 |57 |
|   |E4 |S4 |   |   | P |S3 |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|49 |50 |51 |52 |53 |54 |55 |56 |
|   |   |   | P |E3 |   |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|48 |47 |46 |45 |44 |43 |42 |41 |
|E4 |   |   |   |   | P |   |S3 |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|33 |34 |35 |36 |37 |38 |39 |40 |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |E2 |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|32 |31 |30 |29 |28 |27 |26 |25 |
|S4 |   |   |E3 |   |S2 |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |22 |23 |24 |
|   |E1 |S1 |   |   |   |   |E2 |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|16 |15 |14 |13 |12 |11 |10 |9  |
| P |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
| 1 |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |
|   |   |E1 |   |S1 |   |   |S2 |
|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
```

Comment: _"how can i move my pieces and printing back the board"_ - Are you stuck on how to update your array to reflect where a player has moved after a dice roll, or how to update the display of the board after a move?

Comment: well after a dice roll the player will move a certain amount. Lets say the player rolled a 5. Then he will have to be on box 6. But i dont know how to make the piece move within this multi. array since "array[0]" for col1 is box 64. "array[0]" for col2 is 63 and so on.. it is not the same for all the columns. Basically if i want the player to be on box 6 then it will have to jump columns